# PL/SQL procedure not compiling

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

I have a PL/SQL procedure that is not compiling. The errors are:

1. `Error(3,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge The symbol "INTO" was ignored.`
2. `Error(8,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`.

**My code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findvisitsandlaborcosts
as
begin
select * from SI.customer;
end;
/
```

I have googled an online syntax checker and it says on the first line there is an error. But WHERE?!? It seems to be correct. I have googled the syntax of declaring a procedure and I have cross-checked many times. It must be something simple that I am overlooking...

Comment: You need to save the results somewhere.  A stored procedure can't just run a query.  There is nowhere to put the results.

Comment: Where are you getting the *PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO"*? I don't see any `into` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a PLSQL code, you need a placeholder to keep results of a SELECT query. Since PLSQL engine is expecting INTO clause within SELECT statement.

To begin with, you can select a set of columns and assign their values to local variables.

Your code should be like this -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findvisitsandlaborcosts
as
v_column1 SI.customer.column1%type;
v_column2 SI.customer.column2%type;
begin
select column1, column2 into v_column1, v_column2 from SI.customer;
end;
/
```

Note - you need to replace column1 and column2 with actual column names before running this code at your end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results to get displayed on the caller of the procedure, then you would define an out parameter and print the records outside of the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findvisitsandlaborcosts(x out sys_refcursor)
as
begin
open x for 
select * from dual;
end;
/

--Note this block of code needs to be run in sqlci or sqldeveloper
define m ref cursor;

exec findvisitsandlaborcosts(:x);

print x;
```

Oracle 12c has support for implict return results

Have a look at this link
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1